# Does anyone know the script to auto resize my website for a smart phone browser

Tags: javascript, web, new-operator, smartphone

Does anyone know the script to auto resize my website for a smart phone browser.
Please help if you can.Thank you:)
http://www.anthonycalleja.com

Answer (score 0):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/
There's a mobile version of jquery

http://cpojer.net/MooTools/mobile/Demos/
And a mobile version of mootools as well

Both frameworks are a great start to building a version of your site for easy compatability and detection of mobile browsers

Answer (score 0):

Use adaptive CSS. Look at this:
http://adapt.960.gs/

This can be a good start for you.